# Active Directory to OpenLDAP synchronisation

Tags: openldap

We have a domain controller with `Active Directory` with a number of basic users with custom attributes. We are looking for a way to synchronise the active directory users to `OpenLDAP` (currently running on Debian 6) and wondered if anyone has experience in doing this who could provide some pointers.

There is [this project](http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/1.2/howtos/activedirectory), but it's guides are basic and is missing AD to `OpenLDAP` (it does have the vice-versa)

The hope is that every time a change is made in `Active Directory` it's pushed to the `OpenLDAP server` so that the users can be queried there. We don't want to just forward the requests as sometimes the `Active Directory` server will not be available.

I'd be greatful for any advice or suggestions in this area.

Answer (score 1):

I've just read your questions and would like to answer it. Yes, there is an even easy way to synchronize your Active Directory users to OpenLDAP. The Linux distribution Univention Corporate Server (UCS), which I work for and which is Debian-based, offers various Active Directory services including a tool called "Active Directory Connection", which creates this automatic synchronization process between a Microsoft Active Directory and the OpenLDAP directory, Univention Corporate Server is using, including the synchronization of passwords, group definitions and other directory service objects. The tool Active Directory Connection thus avoids double, complex and error-prone administration. If you might one day think of replacing your AD domain, UCS offers a migration tool called Active Directory Takeover. This can also be used after having configured Active Directory Connection.

Further information on Active Directory Connection in the UCS manual [please refer this link](http://docs.univention.de/manual-4.0.html#ad-connector:general).

If you want to try UCS and the a.m. tools, which you can access via the in UCS integrated Univention App Center, download an ISO or VM image by [this link](https://www.univention.com/downloads/ucs-download/).

Comment: Before 4 years ago I have edited this answer, but now this answer helped me to deploy AD integration. Great project with many services.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2023 (nine years on) I would use a Samba server as a full Domain Controller in the AD environment, synchronised to the existing Windows DCs. You can use it to enhance AD availability. Windows DCs and Samba DCs can all be queried through LDAP